# Getting just the latest price in a joined tables

Tags: laravel

I have 2 tables like this:

### Product table

```
+----+-----------+------------+
| id |    name   |   price    |
+----+-----------+------------+
|  1 | Product 1 |         20 |
|  2 | Product 2 |         10 |
|  3 | Product 3 |         50 | 
|  4 | Product 4 |         40 | 
+----+-----------+------------+
```

### prices table

```
+----+-------+------------+---------------------+
| id | price | product_id |     created_at      |
+----+-------+------------+---------------------+
|  1 |    20 |          1 | 2014-06-21 16:00:00 |
|  2 |    10 |          1 | 2014-06-21 17:00:00 |
|  3 |    50 |          2 | 2014-06-21 18:00:00 |
|  4 |    40 |          2 | 2014-06-21 19:00:00 |
+----+-------+------------+---------------------+
```

in my index.blade.php I have:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
       @foreach($prices as $price)
         <tr>
            <td scope="row>">{{$product->id}}</td>
            <td >{{$product->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$price->price}}</td>
         </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

but how do I get it that where the `{{ $price->price }}` is that i only get the latest price to be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your code to this

In your Product.php create a relationship

```
public function prices() {
    return $this->hasMany(Price::class);
}
```

```
@foreach($products as $product)

         <tr>
            <td scope="row>">{{$product->id}}</td>
            <td >{{$product->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$product->prices()->latest()->price}}</td>
         </tr>

    @endforeach
```

Comment: if i would do that i get **Call to undefined method App\Product::prices() (View:**

Comment: @RicardoPlompen Adjusted my answer

Comment: **Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$price** this is what i will get after i did the last change in the product.php

Comment: That's because you are doing something like `$product->prices()->latest()->$price` instead of the proper `$product->prices()->latest()->price`, please check if you didn't do a typo there.

Comment: I have copied your line of code what u typed, even then it says that error message **Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$price (View: ** do u know what it could been then ?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `$product->prices()->latest()->first()->price`